# I can not login to MySQL with XAMPP

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, xampp

I want to know how to reset my username and password for MySQL. The problem is that I have XAMPP installed and everything worked fine, but one day I could not get to phpmyadmin and I got this:

[image: my error]

I've tried many forms and can not connect to MySQL. I reinstalled XAMPP but still not working.

Can I get help regenerate the user and password?

Comment: Comment: MySQL in XAMPP is in the port 3307

Answer (score 1):

Go to `phpMyAdmin` folder. In my case, it is

```
C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin
```

Edit this file `config.inc.php`.
Change below config as mentioned in the comment:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'; /*change 'config' to 'cookie'*/
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true; /*change true to false.*/
```

Now when you go to phpAdmin page(`http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`), it asks the username and password:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can go on http://localhost/security/ to change the root password.

You can also edit the root password simply using SQL.
Install a free SQL Editor (HeidiSQL) and use the query:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('your_password') WHERE User='root'
```

That should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin it's trying to connect to the database with user root and no password. Check config.inc.php for this parameters and change them to your user/pass (needs to be a full privileged user i think).
You can check your credentials using the mysql-cli:

```
$ mysql -u <user> -p <password>
```

Where `<user>` and `<password>` are your database credentials.

If you want to do a fresh install you need to remove the mysql data dir (var/lib/mysql generally).

Answer (score -1):

To enable remote access to phpMyAdmin from other hosts, follow these steps:

Edit the etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf file in your XAMPP installation directory (usually, /opt/lampp).

Within this file, find the block below:

AllowOverride AuthConfig
  Require local
  ...
Update this block and replace Require local with Require all granted, so that it looks like this:

AllowOverride AuthConfig
  Require all granted
  ...
Save the file and restart the Apache server using the XAMPP control panel.

You should now be able to access phpMyAdmin from other hosts.

Comment: dont install xampp with user root, create before other user account and install it with this account.